# Как сделать чтобы ресурсы не выгружались при сворачивании?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

При сворачивании игры и повторном её запуске я снова наблюдаю длительное время чёрный экран как при первом запуске. Я так понимаю это снова подгружаются текстуры. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при сворачивании они не выгружались?

Answer (score 1):

Не видя реализацию сложно сказать, если используется Screen жизненный цикл при сворачивании приложения - pause, при активации обратно resize, resume - в этих методах ничего нет ресурсоемкого?

Comment: Я загружаю текстуру из assets только в методе creat, в resize я лишь настраиваю OrthographicCamera, а pause и resume абсолютно пустые, их не использую. Собственно никакой особой реализации нет, в приложении пока лишь отрисовка текстуры (правда текстура на 6 МБ вышла)